# More than one display adapters combo

Tags: display-adapter

When I was using adapter combo from **HDMI to DVI then to VGA then to monitor** and it didn't work, so I just go to but without DVI to VGA adapter it works. Actually I still have no idea why I can't just cast it twice.

Currently I face to a new problem, my monitor only allows DVI or VGA input, if I use **micro HDMI to HDMI and then use HDMI to DVI to monitor** would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a poblem of an adapter, but of the rather byzantine design of the `DVI` interface: `DVI` is one of the very few cables, that are able to carry an **analog** signal and a **digital** signal on the same plug.

It is perfectly legitimate for a DVI device, cable or adapter to support only the former or only the latter.

With your first example, you started with `HDMI` - a pure digital signal. The adapter converted it to a `DVI` plug just fine, but of course it only used the pins for the digital signal, leaving the analog ones unused. The next adapter was intended to convert it to `VGA`, which is a purely analog signal. The adapter would use only the analaog pins of `DVI` (where there is no signal) and ignore the digital ones (where there would be one available) - this ofcourse didn't work

In your second example, you start with `micro-HDMI` (digital), convert to `HDMI` (digital again) and finally to DVI - this will work, if the Monitor uses the digital pins of the DVI plug, not only the analog ones.

All monitors I ever saw, that had a DVI plug used these digital pins, so expect it to work fine.

Comment: So the keypoint is DVI interface support both signals. But I still confused with the signal type casting. Because If I directly use HDMI to VGA adapter and then use VGA to VGA cable it works. Finally I want to ask is there any rules that can check it before buy the adapter.